# Adding two columns in where clause

Tags: mysql

This is a fairly simple question that I'm not quite sure how to approach.

If I have two columns, and I want to add them together and see if the result is more than something else, how would I do this?

What I have so far:

```
SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM routes
WHERE destination = :airport
    AND end_time+turn_around > :start_time
    AND end_time < :start_time
```

Comment: Use `:start_time BETWEEN end_time AND end_time + turn_around`

Comment: I strongly recommend avoiding `between` for dates and using separate comparisons.